# Why does Gaussian ignore the opt=maxcycles keyword for optimizations?

Tags: gaussian, geometry-optimization, software-assistance

I have been using both Gaussian09 and Gaussian16 recently to optimize some metal complexes. The Gaussian manual (for both versions) indicates that the maximum number of steps in a geometry optimization can be set by the keyword `maxcycles` in `opt`. However, for every optimization I have done, Gaussian seems to consistently ignore the value set by `maxcycles` and sets its own max. number of steps internally.

Most of the calculations I did have this route line:

```
# opt=maxcycles=200 freq b3lyp/sdd geom=connectivity
```

What I have noticed is that when I am minimizing the geometry, Gaussian sets maximum number of steps to `100` (with the `maxcycles=200`, or to `50` if the maxcycles keyword is omitted. For transition state optimizations, the max. number of steps is set to `145`.

I have seen some discussions regarding this in various forums and mailing lists, but I have found no solution. I have also seen some posts claiming it is a bug, but it keeps happening in Gaussian16 too.

So, my question is— **why does Gaussian ignore the `maxcycles` keyword and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This requires an additional [IOP](https://gaussian.com/overlay1/#iop_(1/152)) to do. It seems that Gaussian sets a separate lower and upper bound on the number of optimization steps that will be performed based on the number of coordinates and `opt(maxcycle=N)` can only set the max value within this range, but not any higher. `IOP(1/152=N)` changes this internal max value, allowing maxcycle to be raised as well. So  you should be able to use `# opt(maxcycles=200) iop(1/152=200) freq b3lyp/sdd geom=connectivity` to increase the allowed number of steps.

*Disclaimer*: There is probably a reason, either physically motivated or due to the structure of the Gaussian code, why/how they set the cap on the number of steps. A large number of optimizations steps can be a sign that you started from a bad structure. It may be fine to remove the cap, but keep in mind the idea of [Chesterton's Fence](https://fs.blog/2020/03/chestertons-fence/) (in short, don't remove a limitation until you understand why its there). IOPs should also be used carefully, as they can conflict with other keyword options.